# Electron Dialog closing refreshes my current page

Tags: html, css, node.js, bootstrap-4, electron

I have an electron app.

It uses Bootstrap v4, Electron v2 amongst some other node modules.

I have a button which opens an electron dialog, the user selects a folder, and at this point, my application BrowserWindow appears to refresh.

I don't want this refresh to occur. I have created a test case which shows this behaviour. No doubt I have made a simple error, please can take a look at this repo to show the test case which reproduces my problem.

https://bitbucket.org/renegadeandy/electron-dialog-problem/src/master/

Comment: I have found out that removing the use of the 'electron-reload' module has solved the problem. But the question remains, why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I am writing a log.txt file to the directory which is being watched by the electron-reload module.

When I write a new record to the log, the file changes, and causes my application to reload! Makes sense - but the combination of my logging & active reload isn't working nicely together.

I have solved it by simply removing electron-reload.